# Angular2 router and localhost/webapp

Tags: angular, router

I was developping my app on a server deployed on localhost/ but now I want to use my app on localhost/webapp, unfortunately it doesn't work. It seems that angular2 try to redirect my app to localhost/ (by removing the webapp). How can I configure angular2 to works on an specific front like "/webapp"?

thanks

Comment: Try `imports: [..., RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes, {useHash: true}]` in `AppModule`. If this fixes your issue you might need to configure your server for HTML5 pushState. You can also try to add `{provide:APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/webapp'}` to `providers: [....]` of your `AppModule`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud set base haref

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#basics-base-href

```
<base href="/webapp">
```